# How can I create a regular expression to exclude a particular character string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list that is filled with items and I don't want the first item to be selected so how do I write a regular expression that doesn't match it (excludes it, triggers an error) in asp.net.

Comment: Why would you need a regexp for that? A simple string comparison seems more appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regular expression for that? If you have a list, you can take the first element and check it's value.

Comment: Can it be done on the client side on an asp control like one of the validation controls?

Comment: I want to use it with the validation required and validation summary controls.

Comment: you can try this..ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: @errorstacks, thanks for your answer before, worked perfectly. :) Put your answer back up so I can accept it.

Comment: @Steve I did that you can do , if it really helps you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use requirefield validator....

Code For .Aspx File-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_season" runat="server"  CssClass="pagedropdown">
                 </asp:DropDownList></td>
                  <td style="width: 10px; height: 46px;" align="left" valign="top" >
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_season"
                      ErrorMessage="Select Season">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Code For .CS File-

```
ddl_season.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select one--", ""));    
ddl_season.Items.Add(new ListItem("John Player", "JP"));    
ddl_season.Items.Add(new ListItem("Miss Player", "MP"));    
ddl_season.Items.Add(new ListItem("WillsClassic", "WC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your drop down to other list that not contain first element of your list